# When I change site url and wordpress url from general settings, Forbidden You don't have permission to access Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I had placed an "index.html" file in the "public" folder to show a maintenance page while the website was under construction. Initially, I had set up WordPress at "siteurl.com/wp". However, today, I removed the "/wp" extension from the settings and entered the site URL without it. I also deleted the "index.html" file that was used during the construction phase. However, I am currently encountering a "Forbidden - You don't have permission" error when attempting to access the site. Additionally, I am unable to access the WordPress admin panel.

Can you help me resolve this issue?

To resolve the issue, I've been trying to fix it by accessing phpMyAdmin and going to the wp_options table. In the wp_options table, I change the page URL to the correct one, which is "https://example.com/wp". Initially, this seems to work, and I can access the site without any errors. However, after a while, the same error returns. When I go back to check the wp_options table, I notice that the URL has reverted back to "https://example.com" even though I had previously changed it to "https://example.com/wp". This cycle continues, and I'm unable to maintain the corrected URL in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should move all files and folders from the /wp directory to the root directory. Then it will work. Else you will have to create/edit an .htaccess file in the root to point all requests to the /wp folder. Else you create an index.php file in the root that `include`s the index.php file in the /wp directory.